# Japanese: Are there computer games that support learning the Genki I and II textbook vocabulary?

Tags: learning-methods, vocabulary, electronic-resources, japanese, l2-acquisition

Are there computer games that use the Genki I and II textbook vocabulary? Sometimes playing a game allows for better memory formation of vocabulary compared to straight memorizing lists and viewing flashcards. For example, I know of Starfruit Cards by Neon Starfruit Lab which is a computer program for matching words, such as English-Japanese and they provide free game card files for the Genki I and II textbooks on the program's website. Are there any other computer program games that work with the Genki vocabulary?